# Javascript, value types as reference

Tags: javascript

I've some scenarios where i need to pass value type as reference without changed the processing function.

1. Example Numeric Types (var limit)

   ```
   var limit = 0; // Need to be the reference type
   var multiCallback = new MultiCallback(limit, function(){});
   for (element in myObject)
   {
       limit++;
       element.DoSomething(multiCallback.callback);
   }

   function MultiCallback(limit, func)
   {
       var calls = 0;

       function callback()
       {
           if (++calls == limit)
           {
              func();
           }
       }

       return {
          callback : callback
       }
   }
   ```
2. Examble Function Types

   ```
   var resizeCallback = function(){};
   $(window).resize(resizeCallback);

   function showPage()
   {
      resizeCallback = resizePage();
   }

   function showLoader()
   {
      resizeCallback = resizeLoader();
   }
   ```

is there a solution

Comment: You can't (*without changed the processing function*...). Numbers and strings in JavaScript are immutable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass Variables by Reference in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the value of a variable will never update the previous value of the variable.

For functions, you can do something like this:

```
var current = function() { ... };
function resizeCallback() {
    return current.apply(this, arguments);
}
// Updating current will work:
current = function() { ... something ... };
```

For other values (primitives and objects), the closest thing is to pass an object:

```
var limit = {value: 0};
function MultiCallback(limit, func) {
    ....
    if (limit.value == ++calls) ...
}
// Changing limit:
limit.value = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no pass by reference in javascript (assigning arguments is not visible to the caller). What you are doing in your function example is modifying a global variable.

You can wrap it with an object and mutations of that object are visible to the caller:

```
var limit = {
    value: 0 
};
```