# Updating Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript, variables, object

I have the following object:

```
var obj1 = {};

obj1.obj2 = {
  prop1: 0
};
```

and the following function:

```
function func1() {
    var p = obj1.obj2.prop1;
    p += 2;
    return p;
 };
```

When updating 'p' it has not updated 'obj1.obj2.prop1'. Instead of 'p' pointing to the original object is it now it's own object by itself? If so how can I make 'p' a pointer?

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7744623/1618257

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `var p = obj1.obj2.prop1;`, you are setting `p` to the value of `prop1`.  So, when you update `p`, you're just updating the value set in `p`.

What you can do is set `p` to `obj1.obj2`.  Then you can update `p.prop1` and it should update `obj1`.

```
function func1() {
    var p = obj1.obj2;
    p.prop1 += 2;
    return p.prop1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have pass-by-reference so you would have to do the following:

```
var obj1 = {};

obj1.obj2 = {
    prop1: 0
};

function func1(obj) {
    obj.obj2.prop1 += 2;
    return obj.obj2.prop1;
};

func1(obj1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`p += 2` is just assigning an other number to `p`, this isn't modifying the object pointed to by `p`.

Do this instead:

```
obj1.obj2.prop1 += 2;
```

or

```
var obj = obj1.obj2;
obj.prop1 += 2;
```