# Object variable scope javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, scope

I don't understand how this scope works. How does the value of `eg.i` get modified in `first` when it is only modified in `second`?

**EXAMPLE**

```
var obj = {

    first: function() {

        var eg = {i: 0}; // eg equals 0 here

        obj.second(eg);
        obj.second(eg);

        console.log(eg.i); // 2
    },

    second: function(eg) {

        ++eg.i;
    }
};
```

How does `eg.i` get modified in the first function as well?

Comment: It's passed by reference into `obj.second()`.

Comment: This answer may help a little bit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `eg` as a parameter to `second`. It might be easier to see if you renamed it:

```
second: function(x) {
    ++x.i;
}
```

It gets modified in the first function because you modify it with the second function.

Comment: So all objects are passed by reference?

Comment: @user2251919: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

When objects are passed in to functions in JS, they're passed in as references rather than values: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass

Comment: But non objects are passed by value?

Comment: Correct. If you pass a JS function a string argument, for example, then this is passed as a value rather than a reference. Imagine that an object exists in memory and all the function gets is a pointer to that object.

Comment: Ok cool, the article explained it well, long story short primitives by value, objects by reference, thank you

Comment: It's incorrect to say that it's passed by reference, as there's no such thing in js. It's more correct to say that they're passed by reference *value*. For more, see Pointy's answer that Blender linked to.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in my comment to Ahmed Nuaman's answer, saying that the argument is passed by reference is incorrect. Proving that is trivial:

```
function change (x) {
    //"replace" x with a different object?
    x = {
        a : 4
    };
}
var o = { a : 6 };
change(o);
console.log(o.a); //6
```

If the argument would truly have been passed by reference, `o.a` would have been `4`. However, the argument is passed by the reference *value* - in this case, the value is simply and object.

And that's why you observed the symptoms presented in the question: When you directly modified the argument, the object passed in was changed.

It's as if you got some ice-cream, then went back to the stand to ask for an extra scoop of vanilla. You still have the same cup, but with that extra something. Using that analogy in the example above, you ask for a new vanilla ice-cream: you still have the old one, and that hasn't changed (well, it may have melted a bit). In a pass-by-reference scenario, you would've dumped your existing ice-cream, and got a brand new one.

As a final note: This is not about scoping rules in js. If `eg` wasn't passed to the `second` function, it would've been unavailable to it.