# When I try to use function to "reuse" the code, it gives wrong results

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code in my google map API:

```
var TC1image0 = "";
var TC1Intensity0 = "";
if (TC1wind0 < 41) { TC1Intensity0="Low Pressure Area"; TC1image0="lpagoogle.png"; }
else if (TC1wind0 < 63) { TC1Intensity0="Tropical Depression";  TC1image0="tdgoogle.png"; }
else if (TC1wind0 < 88) { TC1Intensity0="Tropical Storm"; TC1image0="tsgoogle.png";}
else if (TC1wind0 < 118) { TC1Intensity0="Severe Tropical Storm"; TC1image0="stsgoogle.png"; }
else if (TC1wind0 < 150) { TC1Intensity0="Typhoon"; TC1image0="tygoogle.png"; }
else if (TC1wind0 < 185) { TC1Intensity0="Severe Typhoon"; TC1image0="stygoogle.png"; }
else { TC1Intensity0="Super Typhoon"; TC1image0="sutygoogle.png"; }
```

Before I try to use function, I just repeat the codes every time when I need them, until TC1wind6 / TC1Intensity6 / TC1image6...
It is completely a waste of space. So I try to modify the code using function:

```
function Intensity(TCwind, TCIntensity, TCimage) {
if (TCwind < 41) { TCIntensity="Low Pressure Area"; TCimage="lpagoogle.png"; }
else if (TCwind < 63) { TCIntensity="Tropical Depression";  TCimage="tdgoogle.png"; }
else if (TCwind < 88) { TCIntensity="Tropical Storm"; TCimage="tsgoogle.png";}
else if (TCwind < 118) { TCIntensity="Severe Tropical Storm"; TCimage="stsgoogle.png"; }
else if (TCwind < 150) { TCIntensity="Typhoon"; TCimage="tygoogle.png"; }
else if (TCwind < 185) { TCIntensity="Severe Typhoon"; TCimage="stygoogle.png"; }
else { TCIntensity="Super Typhoon"; TCimage="sutygoogle.png"; }
};
```

and I call the function like this:

```
var TC1wind0 = 65;
var TC1image0 = "";
var TC1Intensity0 = "";
Intensity(TC1wind0, TC1Intensity0, TC1image0);
```

The correct result should store "Tropical Storm" in TC1Intensity0 and "tsgoogle.png" in TC1image0. However it does not give correct result as the above "waste-of-space" method. Instead, the function seems not working. Both TC1Intensity0 and TC1image0 still give "". Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the three parameters you are passing are just strings, javascript will pass them by value. This means that making a change to `TCwind` inside the function will not change `TCwind` outside the function.

The most straight forward way to do that is to return the values in an object:

```
var result = Intensity(65, '', '');
var TCwind = result.TCwind;
var TCimage = result.TCimage;
var TCIntensity = result.TCIntensity;

function Intensity(TCwind, TCIntensity, TCimage) {
    /* snip */
    return {
        TCwind: TCwind,
        TCIntensity: TCIntensity,
        TCimage: TCimage
    };
};
```

For more information about pass by value / pass by reference, check out some of these other questions:

- [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)
- [Does Javascript pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference)
- [Pass Variables by Reference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have a further question, a similar one but should be more complicated:
I have:
`function TCDirection(PlaceLatlng, TCLatlng) {
 var TCDirectiontoHK = (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading (PlaceLatlng, TCLatlng));
 if (TCDirectiontoHK<0)
 TCDirectiontoHK = Math.round(360+TCDirectiontoHK);
 else
 TCDirectiontoHK = Math.round(TCDirectiontoHK);
};`
and I want to call it like `TCDirection(HKLatlng, TC1Latlng0);`
Of course it cannot work.. How can I get the bearing as expected?

Comment: @hkson you need to return something from the function and assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

More simple would be, that you don't pass the vars as parameters.
Than the function would write in the global vars.

```
function Intensity(TC1wind0){
[...]
}


var TC1wind0 = 65;
var TC1image0 = "";
var TC1Intensity0 = "";
Intensity(TC1wind0);
```