# angular, pass a scope into a function (passing scope as variable?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass a scope into a function and I can't seem to get it to work correctly. Here's what I have -

```
ng-click="clickFunction(scope1)"

//the function 
$scope.clickFunction = function(passedScope){

      passedScope = false;
      console.log($scope.scope1);
```

So - it's prett straight forward I just want to pass in the scope and set it to false in this click. When I log the scope after changing it hwever it still says it's true. I also tried -

```
  $scope.passedScope
```

What I am trying to do is set $scope.scope1 = false. It is set in the top of the controller as true and controls a button nearby by that button having ng-disabled="!scope1",  I cant just do a scope1 =!scope! on the click because it goes through a modal to confirm the user wants to complete then runs a   modalInstance.result.then(function () { there I then need to set the passed scope to false. I would just call the scope directly, but I'm trying to make a function which I can use across multiple delete functions, thus trying to pass he scope that needs changing to false.

I was thinking I could just pass the scope through the function.

Thanks!

**update**
According to what @Josep showed me today I was able to make a work around by passing the scope as a string like so

```
   ng-click="clickFunction('scope1')"
```

and then doing

```
$scope[passedScope] = false;
```

Comment: @Josep the click function does a ton of other things, i cut them out because they arent relevant, this just needs to set this scope to true if certain other things happen within the click function.

Comment: where is scope1 first declared/used?

Comment: It isnt clear at all from the example what you are trying to do.  scope = false?

Comment: @ajmajmajma I have updated my answer, I think that now I understood what you were trying to do, please have a look at it.

Comment: @mccainz I tried to elaborate a little more. I am trying to set the scope to false yes, but I would like to pass it so it is dynamic across multiple different uses of this function. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to pass the current scope of a part of your view to a function, the way to do it would be:

```
ng-click="clickFunction(this)"
```

But then in your function you should be treating that scope like this:

```
$scope.clickFunction = function(passedScope){
   passedScope.somePropertyOfTheScope = false;//<---Notice the difference with the code that you are suggesting.
```

**You can't set the `scope` to `false`**, you can set one of its properties to `false`, but not the scope itself. That wouldn't make any sense because **[`scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)** is an object that holds a set of properties, events and functions. Some of them inherited from its scope ancestors up to `$rootScope`, and some of them are custom.

**Maybe what you are trying to do is to pass one of the properties of the `scope` as a parameter of a function, so that you can change it in that function**. However, in javascript the only way to pass a parameter by reference is to pass the object and update one of its properties, if you pass a boolean property to the function, then you will be passing the value of that boolean property, not the reference. Please have a look at this: [Pass Variables by Reference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript).

Comment: The scope I am bringing in is not the model of the click object

Comment: Ah yes, this would explain it, thank you very much for taking the time to answer this!!

Comment: @ajmajmajma no problem! I'm happy to know that I was able to help you.

Comment: I Was able to work around this by what you showed me here today by passing the var name as a string like so - ng-click="clickFunction('scope1')", then doing  $scope[passedScope] = false;

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to [Josep's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26805618/1064325) (which helped me find it out), you could simply call like this:

```
ng-click="clickFunction()"
```

And then in your function you can refer the current scope with `this`:

```
$scope.clickFunction = function() {
   this.somePropertyOfTheScope = false;

   //...
}
```

This is very useful when using `ng-include` that creates a new scope, so `clickFunction` is actually at parent scope.