# Javascript - primitive vs reference types

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

In the below code we are passing an object. So, according to javascript we are passing a reference and manipulating.

```
var a = new Number(10);
x(a);
alert(a);

function x(n) {
n = n + 2;
}
```

But 10 is alerted instead of 12. Why?

Comment: This answer might help you to understand 'pass-by-reference' in javascript http://stackoverflow.com/a/7744623/1793653

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`n` is local to `x` and first it is set to the same reference as global `a`. The right hand side `n + 2` is then evaluated to be a number (primitive).
**The left hand side of the assignment**, `n`, is never evaluated, it **is just an identifier** there. So our local variable is now set to the primitive value of the right hand side. The value referenced by `a` is never actually modified. See

```
var a = new Number(10);
x(a);
alert(a);  // 10

function x(n) {
  alert(typeof n);  // object
  n = n + 2;
  alert(typeof n);  // number
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you compute

```
n + 2
```

this results in a new "native number" even if `n` is indeed a `Number` object instance.

Assigning to `n` then just changes what the local variable `n` is referencing and doesn't change the `Number` object instance. You can see that with

```
n = new Number(10);
console.log(typeof n);     // ---> "object"
console.log(n + 2);        // ---> 12
console.log(typeof (n+2)); // ---> "number"
n = n + 2;
console.log(typeof n);     // ---> "number"
```

In Javascript (or Python or Lisp) there's no way to pass the "address" of a variable so that the called function mutates it. The only thing you can do is passing a setter function... for example:

```
function foo(setter) {
    setter(42);
}

funciton bar() {
    var x = 12;
    foo(function(newx){x = newx;});
    console.log(x); // ---> 42
}
```

Comment: So numbers are immutable right? If `x = new Number(5)` or `x = 5`, there is no operation such that `x` maintains the same reference but has a different value. When I do `console.log(new Number(5))` it gives `Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 5}`. But I'm assuming you can't mutate that `[[PrimitiveValue]]`, right?

Comment: @soktinpk: yes, number an strings are immutable in Javascript. You can however create an object with a `valueOf()` method that can behave like a number in math expressions but that has mutable state you can control.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to answer it with examples:

```
function modify(obj) {
    // modifying the object itself
    // though the object was passed as reference
    // it behaves as pass by value
    obj = {c:3};
}

var a = {b:2}
modify(a);
console.log(a)
// Object {b: 2}

function increment(obj) {
    // modifying the value of an attribute
    // working on the same reference
    obj.b = obj.b + 1;
}

var a = {b:2}
increment(a);
console.log(a)
// Object {b: 3}

function augument(obj) {
    // augument an attribute
    // working on the same reference
    obj.c = 3;
}

var a = {b:2}
augument(a);
console.log(a)
// Object {b: 2, c: 3}
```

Please refer the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34e3hzf9/) for working demo.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is rather simple: because ECMAScript is pass-by-value and *not* pass-by-reference, and your code proves that. (More precisely, it is call-by-sharing, which is a specific kind of pass-by-value.)

See [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/518000/2988) for some additional insight.

ECMAScript uses pass-by-value, or more precisely, a special case of pass-by-value where the value being passed is *always* a pointer. This special case is also sometimes known as call-by-sharing, call-by-object-sharing or call-by-object.

It's the same convention that is used by Java (for objects), C# (by default for reference types), Smalltalk, Python, Ruby and more or less every object-oriented language ever created.

Note: some types (e.g.) `Number`s are actually passed *directly* by value and *not* with an intermediary pointer. However, since those are immutable, there is no observable behavioral difference between pass-by-value and call-by-object-sharing in this case, so you can greatly simplify your mental model by simply treating *everything* as call-by-object-sharing. Just interpret these special cases as internal compiler optimizations that you don't need to worry about.

Here's a simple example you can run to determine the argument passing convention of ECMAScript (or any other language, after you translate it):

```js
function isEcmascriptPassByValue(foo) {
  foo.push('More precisely, it is call-by-object-sharing!');
  foo = 'No, ECMAScript is pass-by-reference.';
  return;
}

var bar = ['Yes, of course, ECMAScript *is* pass-by-value!'];

isEcmascriptPassByValue(bar);

console.log(bar);
// Yes, of course, ECMAScript *is* pass-by-value!,
// More precisely, it is call-by-object-sharing!
```

If you are familiar with C#, it is a very good way to understand the differences between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference for value types and reference types, because C# supports all 4 combinations: pass-by-value for value types ("traditional pass-by-value"), pass-by-value for reference types (call-by-sharing, call-by-object, call-by-object-sharing as in ECMAScript), pass-by-reference for reference types, and pass-by-reference for value types.

(Actually, even if you *don't* know C#, this isn't too hard to follow.)

```csharp
struct MutableCell
{
    public string value;
}

class Program
{
    static void IsCSharpPassByValue(string[] foo, MutableCell bar, ref string baz, ref MutableCell qux)
    {
        foo[0] = "More precisely, for reference types it is call-by-object-sharing, which is a special case of pass-by-value.";
        foo = new string[] { "C# is not pass-by-reference." };

        bar.value = "For value types, it is *not* call-by-sharing.";
        bar = new MutableCell { value = "And also not pass-by-reference." };

        baz = "It also supports pass-by-reference if explicitly requested.";

        qux = new MutableCell { value = "Pass-by-reference is supported for value types as well." };
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var quux = new string[] { "Yes, of course, C# *is* pass-by-value!" };

        var corge = new MutableCell { value = "For value types it is pure pass-by-value." };

        var grault = "This string will vanish because of pass-by-reference.";

        var garply = new MutableCell { value = "This string will vanish because of pass-by-reference." };

        IsCSharpPassByValue(quux, corge, ref grault, ref garply);

        Console.WriteLine(quux[0]);
        // More precisely, for reference types it is call-by-object-sharing, which is a special case of pass-by-value.

        Console.WriteLine(corge.value);
        // For value types it is pure pass-by-value.

        Console.WriteLine(grault);
        // It also supports pass-by-reference if explicitly requested.

        Console.WriteLine(garply.value);
        // Pass-by-reference is supported for value types as well.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = new Number(10);    
x(a);
alert(a);

function x(n) {
    n = n + 2; // NOT VALID as this would essentially mean 10 = 10 + 2 since you are passing the 'value' of a and not 'a' itself
}
```

You need to write the following in order to get it working

```
var a = new Number(10);
x(a);
alert(a);

function x(n) {
    a = n + 2; // reassign value of 'a' equal to the value passed into the function plus 2
}
```

Comment: I am not looking for a working code. Your first set of explanation "10 = 10 + 2" is not right.

Comment: This equation is not valid. As the left hand side is a *number*.

Comment: Right. You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript parameter passing works similar to that of Java.  Single values are passed by value, but object attributes are passed by reference via their pointer values.  A value itself will not be modified in a function, but attributes of an object would be modified.

Consider the following code:

```
function doThis(param1, param2) {
    param1++;
    if(param2 && param2.value) {
        param2.value++;
    }
}

var initialValue = 2;
var initialObject = {value: 2};

doThis(initialValue, initialObject);

alert(initialValue); //2
alert(initialObject.value); //3
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bfm01b4x/

Comment: Java (and JS) objects are passed by name, (the a reference to the object is passed by value). Object arguments (not attributes) are not passed by reference. The terminology matters. 'attribute' in java has a specific meaning which is different to 'field' - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7