# Javascript performance/memory in angular with passing objects around?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a large object, and I mean large with multiple keys and values. Out of the cases below, which would be most performant and less memory intensive, or does it matter?

Global Variable Here

```
var sample = {"keya":"value-a-is-a-huge-nested-map","keyb":"valueb",...many-other-key-value-pairs }
```

CASE A

```
doSomething(sample.keya);
function doSomething(testobject) {
    // 1. do manipulation on it to return a result
}
```

CASE B

```
doSomething(a.keya);
function doSomething(key) {
    // 1. extract the specific key from "sample"
    // 2. do a lookup on the value from "sample"
    // 3. do manipulation on it to return a result
}
```

Now imagine the same case above, but replace the function calls with $scope.$emit and $scope.$on instead of just plain function calls.
Is it safe to assume that using Case 2 is better because your not "emitting" over the value of a large object?

Comment: You're passing references.

Comment: Objects in Javascript are passed by pointer so no copy is created when they are passed to a function.  It is very efficient to pass an object to a function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript