# adding data() to an html element using new operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just wrote a very simple snippet to understand how jQuery `data()` functions and the code is as follows:

```
$(function () {     
        carousel = function() {
          this.prop1 = 1;
          this.prop2 = 'two';
          this.prop3 = 3;  
        }
        var _str = $('#test'),
        $str_data = _str.data();
        console.log($str_data);
        data = _str.data('carousel');

        if (!data) _str.data('carousel' , new carousel());  
        console.log(data);  

        if (!data) {
            console.log('no data');
        }
});
```

Now, the objective of this code was to add data() to the `div` element using the `new` operator and then checking if that piece of data was added, however in my snippet of code in-spite of me adding data to the `div` element using the below line of code:

```
if (!data) _str.data('carousel' , new carousel());
```

When I checked again to see on the next line if data is actually added:

```
if (!data) {
    console.log('no data');
}
```

The test passes, which means no data was added. So what am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't you log `_str.data()` instead of `data` ? So you fetch the new, updated data instead the old var. I dont blieve it is an instance, or is it?

Comment: does your _str.data('carousel') start out with data?  what do you get if you do a console.log of _str.data('carousel') before data = _str.data('carousel'); ?  If you don't have starting data, that setting of 'carouse' will not execute.

Comment: @Taplar , i get `undefined` .

Answer (score 1):

If there is no data, you are updating the data associated with the element but the value referred by the `data` variable is not updated that is why it is still giving `undefined` as its value.

```
$(function () {

    var carousel = function () {
        this.prop1 = 1;
        this.prop2 = 'two';
        this.prop3 = 3;
    }

    var _str = $('#test'),
        $str_data = _str.data();

    console.log($str_data);

    var data = _str.data('carousel');

    if (!data) {
        //create a new carousel and assign it to data so that it gets a new value
        data = new carousel();
        //store the new carousel value
        _str.data('carousel', data);
    }

    console.log(data);

    if (!data) {
        console.log('no data');
    }

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zx7xk8px/)

Comment: or should't    `_str.data('carousel', (new carousel()));` also work ??

Comment: @Tenali_raman that will set the data of the element but the local variable `data` will not be updated

Comment: are you refering to the data inside if as local ??

Comment: @Tenali_raman `data = _str.data('carousel');` this variable is not updated after new object is created

Comment: ! ohh yes , moment of realization , can you explain in sentence , why that happens , is that because `data` holds the old  value ?

Comment: ! what do you mean by 'something like that' ? :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not updating the `data` variable's value. You need either to set again the `data` value after setting the carousel or to call directly the jquery function `.data()` as the example bellow:

```
data = _str.data('carousel');

// this condition is not updating the variable defined above
if (!data) {
    _str.data('carousel' , new carousel());
}

console.log(data);  

// you have to update the variable value or to call as
if (!_str.data('carousel')) {
    console.log('no data');
}
```

Comment: Why does `_str.data('carousel'` work and `data` not work , when both are actually the same , because `data = _str.data('carousel');` , if you can explain that , i'll accept your answer !.

Comment: The accepted answer of the following question is exlaining exactly what `pass-by-reference` means and that this is not available in javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript