# Reset value of select passed as argument

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some dependent selects and I want to reset all next

```
<select ng-change="applyChanges(model.v2)"
            ng-model="model.v1" name="v1"
            ng-options="v as v.Name for v in vs" class="form-control" required></select>

<select ng-change="applyChanges(model.v3)" ng-model="model.v2"
            name="v2"
            ng-options="vv as vv.Name for vv in model.v1.v2" class="form-control"
            required ng-disabled="!model.v1"></select>
```

But how to reset select values on ng-change method ?

```
$scope.applyChanges = function (arg) {
        if (!_.isUndefined(arg)) {
            arg = "?";
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case when you say `arg = '?'`, you are only changing the value of the local variable `arg` the value referred by `model.v2` is not changed.

So pass the `model` and the property to be changed as arguments to the function like

```
<select ng-change="applyChanges(model, 'v2')"
            ng-model="model.v1" name="v1"
            ng-options="v as v.Name for v in vs" class="form-control" required></select>
```

then

```
$scope.applyChanges = function (model, prop) {
        if (!_.isUndefined(model[prop])) {
            model[prop] = "?";
        }
};
```

- [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)
- [Pass Variables by Reference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript)
- [Does Javascript pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference)