# Is it good practice to manipulate a function parameter from within a function?

Tags: javascript

Is it generally acceptable (or frowned upon) in good JavaScript practice to modify a function parameter of type reference value (Object) from inside a function?

I’m aware of how it works in that all function parameters are passed by value and the reference value parameter is just a pointer to an Object’s memory location.

Thank you!

edit: I've removed "pass by reference" from title and description to make wording more correct and to avoid confusion for readers. Correct answer (and helpful comments) still apply

Comment: [That's not really what "pass by reference" means.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611) In any case, manipulating the contents of an object is a perfectly fine thing to do, assuming your system architecture is amenable to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to know that it **isn't** passed by reference, so I can't imagine what "treating it" like it were would look like. Remember, because there is no pass-by-reference in JavaScript, that means you can't reach out from the function and change the **variable** whose value was passed in (not the object it refers to). It's neither good or bad practice; it's impossible.

```
function foo(a) {
   a  = {"different stuff": "here"};
}
var b = {stuff: "here"};
foo(b);               // `foo`'s assignment to `a` has nothing whatsoever
                      // to do with `b` and has no effect on it
console.log(b.stuff); // "here"
```

In general, it's perfectly acceptable to modify the *state* of an object through an object reference passed (by value) into a function, if that's what you're asking:

```
function foo(a) {
   a.stuff = a.stuff.toUpperCase();
}
var b = {stuff: "here"};
foo(b);
console.log(b.stuff); // "HERE"
```

That has nothing at all to do with pass-by-reference.

There are programming paradigms, some of which are sometimes used in JavaScript, where that would not be okay and you'd have to clone and return a new object. Those are not the *norm* in JavaScript, and if you're using them you'll know. If you're not, it's standard practice to modify object states like that.

Comment: "In general, it's perfectly acceptable to modify the state of an object through an object reference passed (by value) into a function, if that's what you're asking:"
Yes this is better wording, forget pass by reference : )
So, in practice this is an acceptable technique to do?

Comment: @Dave: Unless you're using JavaScript for hardcore [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), yes. The vast majority of people don't. There is a larger "functional programming in JavaScript" community, though, than I've seen in other languages that weren't designed to be functional (as Haskell is, for instance). Not big in on a percentage basis, but still, they're there,  But again, if you were using functional programming, you'd know. :-)

Comment: Also thank you for the clarity that there is only pass by value in JavaScript.

Comment: Haha yes, definitely not functional, but I am writing JavaScript in a less common way. It's keyword driven automated testing framework that uses Sahi Pro to allow our QA team to write automated tests. In parallel to writing the framework, I'm reading 2 books, **Professional JavaScript for Web Developers** and **JavaScript: The Good Parts** which have been great reads.

Comment: @Dave: Just a word of caution on that second one. Crockford is a smart, well-informed person, but in his writing he fails sometimes to distinguish his opinion from fact. For instance, there is some flat-out incorrect information in the inheritance part of *The Good Parts* about constructor functions (which he dislikes). It's well worth reading Crockford, so long as you keep that in mind. :-) Separately, I'll just note that since writing that book, he's gone off in a much more functional direction, so if you read some of his more recent work, you'll see that influence. Best,