# How to pass a property by reference

Tags: javascript, knockout-es5-plugin

Is there a way to pass an object property to a function by reference instead of by value?

ES5 properties can have getters and setters. How to pass a variable that uses the getters and setters instead of the result of the getter?

Right now I have to pass a reference to the whole object, not just the single property I want.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to pass an object property to a function by reference instead of by value?

No. In fact it doesn't ultimately make a lot of sense to "pass an object property", as the notion of a "property" doesn't exist without the entity that it is a property of.

If this is simply a matter of encapsulation and not wanting to leak full control, you can always get creative.  E.g.,

```
var obj = {
    sensitive: 'do not share me!',
    public: 'hi there',
    setPublic: function(val) {
        this.public = val;
    }
};

function someFunction(setter) {
    setter('new value');
}

someFunction(obj.setPublic.bind(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do exactly what you're asking because no matter what it's source, value types (i.e. non-objects/arrays) will be passed by value. However, if you create a get/set function, you could pass the function bound to the object.

```
var obj = {
  _val: 0,
  val: function(x) {
    if (x !== undefined) {
      this._val = x;
    } else {
      return this._val;
    }
  }
}

function doStuff(prop) {
  if (prop() > 1) {
    prop(0);
  }
}

doStuff(obj.val.bind(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always pass two arguments, the object and the property name:

```
function change(obj, prop, newVal) {
  obj[prop] = newVal;
}

var obj = { foo: 1 };

change(obj, 'foo', 99);
console.log(obj); // => { foo: 99 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no because, as you have already mentioned in your question, primitive types are passed by value.

There is an [interesting SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7744623/4963159) which explains it in details and also links to [a very detailed blog post](http://whatsthepointy.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/javascript-does-not-have-pass-by.html).

However if you really do need to do so, you can create a wrapper object for the specific property you are trying to pass around, however this is a workaround more than a solution.