# Javascript Function Expressions

Tags: javascript

I have recently been trying to learn javascript and have a couple of questions.

When you create a function expression:

```
var greet = function(){
    console.log('Hi');
}
```

Is that creating a function object and having the variable "greet" point to that function object in memory?

My second question if you have a function like this:

```
function log(a){
    console.log(a);
}
```

Then you make a call to that function:

```
log(greet); //greet is the function expression declared above.
```

So I know that when a function object is created there are two properties that are given to the object. The name (if provided, otherwise anonymous) and a code property which stores the code contained inside the parentheses of the function. Now I am a little confused on where the parameter "a" in the log function gets attached to in a function object. Is "a" just another property of the function object log and it simply just points to the memory address of anything that is passed into the log function? Where in this case it was a function expression called greet. Any input would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass Variables by Reference in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript)

Comment: To your first question: yes. Which is what happens in a function declaration too, it's **when** that happens that makes a difference.

Comment: @Typo That post did not help to answer my question. I am referring to something completely different.

Comment: Try the following article at the comp.lang.javascript FAQ: [*Javascript Closures*](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/). While it uses ECMAScript ed 3 language, it's a comprehensive explanation of how an execution context is created and how identifiers are resolved on the scope chain and object `[[Prototype]]` chain. Just remember that the terms have changed since then, but it all happens exactly the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a function is called as in:

```
log(greet)
```

then the identifier *log* is resolved in the current execution context and, if not found, is searched along the scope chain, ending at the global execution context. If not found, an error is thrown.

In this case, *log* has been defined using a function declaration so it exists in the global scope so is found. Its value is checked to make sure it's callable (again, if not, an error is thrown) if it is, it's called.

In the call, the identifier *greet* is resolved and its value passed to the function. If *greet* can't be resolved (i.e. it doesn't exist on the scope chain), an error is thrown. In this case, it resolves to a reference to the function assigned to *greet*.

When *log* is executed, a new execution context is created. The function declaration for *log* defines a formal parameter *a* (in its formal parameter list), so *a* is created as a local variable for *log*. The values in the call are passed to identifiers in the formal parameter list in order, so the value of *greet* is assigned to *a*. Note that initialisation and creation of a new execution context occurs every time a function is called.

The same process is followed when calling:

```
console.log(a);
```

so that within *console.log*, the reference to *greet* is passed as the first parameter, so it now references the *greet* function.

The behaviour of *console.log* is entirely implementation dependent so the internals are unknown, but for functions most tend to just call the function's *toString* method.

It's a handy feature of ECMAScript that an arguments object is created of the arguments passed to functions, so the values passed are always available as numeric properties of the arguments object if there is no parameter for them to be assigned to. So *console.log* doesn't have to define any formal parameters, it can just loop over its *arguments* object and process the passed values in turn.

Comment: OH that makes sense. So basically the variable "a" is just a variable in the execution context of the function greet. It has no connection to the function object that is created for greet. "a" is simply used in the execution context for the function greet correct?

Comment: @ClayHorder— *a* is a formal parameter of *log*, not *greet*. It's passed a value (reference to *greet*) that it then passes to *log*. Oh, I think I just summarised the above post on one sentence…

Comment: It should be noted that the `arguments` object has a lot of problems both in its usage and in that it often makes it hard for browsers to optimize your code. It will eventually be going away; it will be replaced [rest parameters](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-rest-parameters-and-defaults/).

Comment: @UselessCode—I don't see any major issues with *arguments* from a programming perspective, it will be a long time before it goes away (if it ever does) or rest parameters can be used safely on the web. Rest parameters provide some benefits, but don't completely replace *arguments*. At one time, Chrome (or perhaps Opera, I forget which) implemented *arguments* as an Array. I think the over use of inefficient libraries (often many times bigger than the actual data content of a page) is a vastly bigger and far easier to fix problem than optimisation of minor issues with language features.