# Function that modifies function argument and persists

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want a function that modifies a variable e.g.:

```
private _buildUrlCategories(url: string) {
  url += ";categories=" + this.findForm.value.categories;
}

private _buildUrl() {
  let url = "/#/find";
  this._buildUrlCategories(url); //now url should be bigger
}
```

If it can't be done then obviously I can just return the url and do `url += this._buildUrlCategories(url)`.

Is this possible? Is this a technique that has a name?

Comment: or, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, it can't be done.

From the [TypeScript specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#1-introduction):

> TypeScript is a syntactic sugar for JavaScript. TypeScript syntax is a superset of ECMAScript 2015 (ES2015) syntax. Every JavaScript program is also a TypeScript program.

TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript and in JavaScript, arguments can not be passed by reference (well, [except objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7744623/3861083)).