# Confirmation of string behavior as an argument in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Please can someone confirm the following assertions about the code below?

- the contents (i.e. the string it is pointing to) of `str` will not be copied when it is passed as an argument into `f`
- that parameter `p`, created in the execution context instantiated for the call to `f` is a value which is a reference to the memory containing the interned value "foo" (hence no copy occurred)
- that `String#slice` does not copy `p`

  ```
  var str = 'foo';
  function f(p) {
    return p.slice(2); // creates a new string with "o" as the contents
  }
  f(str);
  ```

Comment: I guess there should be `f(str);`, not `f(p);`

Comment: Thanks, updated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass Variables by Reference in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript)

Comment: Strings are basically immutable, and the copy in underlying implementation differs across engines.

Comment: Also this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I confirm.

*P.S.: is it really all you needed?*

Comment: you should provide some details on why you confirm this, including references, examples and/or explanations