# duktape, modify variable argument in native C code

Tags: duktape

I'm trying to modify a variable passed in an argument in a native function like this:

```
var MyVar = 'foo';
myNativeFunc(MyVar);
```

and inside my native, I can read the content of MyVar, with :

```
std::string(duk_to_string(ctx, 0));
```

but, I need to modify the value of this variable inside native function.
what is the best way for does it? (I can't use the return statement) thanks.

Comment: Your heading says C lang but your code is C++. Please edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible as it would implement pass-by-reference (which is not supported in JS). Read also the answer to the question [Pass Variables by Reference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript#7744623)

So, either pass in an object reference and change the object properties or use a return value.

Comment: Thank you, i become crazy when i searching the solution ( looking for duktape stack manipulation... ) , i will use the object properties , it's more easy.

Comment: If you find my answer helping you then pls accept it.