# What is node in javascript and how does it work in context of 'refs' in reactJs

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am learning javascript, specifically, react.js,I am following a [basic redux tutorial](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html), but having problems in understanding the folowing jsx syntax.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addTodo } from '../actions'
let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
  let input

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        onSubmit={e => {            
          e.preventDefault()
          if (!input.value.trim()) {
            return
          }
          dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
          input.value = ''
        }}
      >
        <input
          ref={node => {
            input = node
          }}
        />
        <button type="submit">
          Add Todo
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
AddTodo = connect()(AddTodo)

export default AddTodo
```

On searching what I could only figure out is that `ref` is a prop for reference (similar to a unique Id) that helps us identifying elements and do stuff with them.

**My Question(s)**:
If I understand ref correctly, (please correct me if I am wrong)

(a) In the above example what will be the possible value of the prop `ref`. In other words, how will the element look when it is actually rendered on the web page?

(b) What does  `node` here refers to? Does the function `node => { input = node }` return anything?

Answer (score 0):

> (a) In the above example what will be the possible value of the prop
>   ref. In other words, how will the element look when it is actually
>   rendered on the web page

The value of the property ref will be a callback function with one argument of type [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement). It will look like this: `<input>`

> (b) What does  node here refers to? Does the function node => { input
>   = node } return anything?

`node` is an instance of actual DOM element of type HTMLInputElement that corresponds to your `<input>` tag. This function should not return anything.

More info on refs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Comment: so, if `ref` is not rendered, how does it work. what's the use of providing a callback function here? how react uses it ?

Comment: This is a react way for to interact with child component instances. It allows you to get hold of the in memory reference to the actual rendered DOM element or compoentnt instance. This is done to allow you to imperatively perform some operations on the actual elements. For example if you use bootstrap tooltips you would like in `componentDidMount` to call `$(this.input).tooltip(options)`. The preferred way of getting `this.input` is to assign it using `ref`

Comment: assign `it`... assign what?  I am feeling so awkward, but can you  please explain by example .. How will `ref` help me to call the `tooltip()` function on `this.input` ?

Comment: In ref you will have the code that assign value to `this.input` member: `ref={(c) => this.input = c}` and then later in componentDidMount you can use this member to do what you need to.

Comment: Ok still finding it difficult to comprehend, can you kindly refer me to some resources, especially, where can I find such example?

Comment: Sure. Have you looked at the link in post? Here it is again, they give nice examples of `ref` usage: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: yes I did, I am finding problem in understanding how does that `textInput` thing come from?

Comment: textInput is just a field in CustomTextInput class. You can name it whatever - its your class internal field. This is how you define fields in classes in javascript.

Comment: also, it seems to me that the function takes an input element as an argument and sets the `textInput` element to this element. Sounds like it replaces the DOM with this element. Clearly this is not the case but then why it sets the `textInput = input`

Comment: same was the case in my question.

Comment: textInput contain the reference to dom element so you can later use it. But assigning it does not replace it in dom. Its just a reference to element in tree. You cannot replace tree node like this.

Comment: Ok,  what would be the output of  `console.log(textInput)`?  In my imagination it would be like `<input />` and what would be the console.log(input) give? it will be essentially `<input>` as you mentioned in your first comment. so it means we are replacing the contents of `textInput`.  Is it so?

Comment: You are replacing content of textInput field. It contain reference to DOM element. By assigning something to textInput you modify value of this field that is only "refer" to actual DOM node. You do not replace dom node itself. There is no such thing in javascript as passing by reference, check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript

Comment: Ok. I just comprehended that textInput is nothing yet. It's just a variable which will refer to the input element AFTER the textInput=input is executed.

Comment: https://www.reactenlightenment.com/basic-react-components/6.9.html, this link helped me.