# How can I bind a local variable to another local variable when it changes

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm working on an ionic 2 project which uses angular 2.

I just have this in mind if there's a way I can create a variable to bind to 
another variable(s).

Let's say,

```
let x = 1;

let y = x;
```

where y will have the exact value of x even when it changes.

And if it does work, can I also do this?

```
let x = 1;

let y = 1;

let z = x + 1;
```

I'd like to know if this is possible or not. 
Just had this in mind. Thanks and cheers!

Comment: You cannot. You can achieve this behavior with Objects but not with literals

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7744623/2653611

Answer (score 0):

In Angular components and providers this is solved with property accessors:

```
class SomeService {
  x = 1;

  get y() {
    return this.x;
  }

  get z() {
    return this.x + 1;
  }
}
```

It's not possible to pass scalar value by reference (and there are usually no reasons to do that in Angular).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not allow passing reference of the primitive types. So you can achieve this by wrapping them in an object.

```
let x = { 
    value: 1,
    get z() { return this.value + 1}
}

let y = x;

y.value = 10;   // Now x.value is also 10
```