# Array overwrite not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wrote a simple function to overwrite an array as follows:

```
function overwrite(arr) {
    let temp = [3, 2, 1];
    arr = temp;
}

let myarray = [1, 2, 3];
overwrite(myarray);
console.log(myarray);
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

The console output still shows the original array.  How come?

By the way, I did figure out how to do it.  I feel like the above approach should've worked but didn't, and so I am curious to know why.

Comment: Variable scope.

Comment: It doesn't pass by reference, only the value is passed

Comment: @Huangism.  I thought arrays are always passed by reference.  What am I missing?

Comment: Here's a great answer for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13104500/4518022

Comment: There are lots of questions related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript

Comment: @sarneeh thanks for the link.  I get it now, it pass a copy of the reference.

Answer (score 3):

You hand over an object reference of the array and you assign the array in local scope of `overwrite`.

To update the original array, you need to empty the array and splice the values.

```js
function overwrite(arr) {
    let temp = [3, 2, 1];
    arr.splice(0, arr.length, ...temp);
}

let myarray = [1, 2, 3];
overwrite(myarray);

console.log(myarray);
```

Comment: Aren't array's passed by reference?  My thinking was with "arr = temp;" it updates arr reference with temp reference.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @MrCisco, in the scope of `overwrite`, you get an updated array, but the old reference is lost after assigning a new array.

Comment: Turns out you can't overwrite the reference in arr.  I did end up using splice though (I should've been more clear in my post).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works behind the scene :

myarray contains the memory reference of [1, 2, 3], and for clarity, let's name it **&myarray** .
Now when you pass myarray to the function overwrite(), the javascript engine assigns **&myarray** to **arr** (something like : arr = &myarray;). So, in this step you have something like this :

```
myarray = &myarray;
arr = &myarray;
```

And when you're assigning temp to arr, what you're basically doing is :

```
arr = &temp; // You're changing where arr point to, not myarray
```

So myarray **still points to &myarray** (a reference to [1, 2, 3]) and arr points to &temp (a reference to [3, 2, 1]), and that's why the value is not changed.

And here is an illustration to visualize what I've explained :

[image]