# How to synch the values of two different variables, so when the value of one changes, the other does too

Tags: javascript

I need to make something like this, but I don't know how

```
var a = 5

function myFunction(x){
  if(x != 4) {
    x = 4;
  } 
}

myFunction(a);

//afterward, a should equal 4
```

The clue is, when `this.x` changes, var `a` should change too (I need to be able to make complicated operations on lots of variables and I want to do so by invoking a function)

Is it even possible?

Comment: You should probably read some about Closures in Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: What you are asking for is called "pass by reference", it means instead of passing the value of `a`, you want to pass a reference to `a` when you run the function. Sadly, this is impossible in js, according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7744623/8759952

Comment: While pass-by-reference doesn't exist in JS, you can reassign values.  So you could simply use `return x` at the end of the function, and call it with `a = myFunction(a)`.  Of course this doesn't handle your multiple variables scenario.  For that, you might want to pass an object with multiple properties....

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Your comment was true, I was over simplifying the idea, which was wrong of me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not the same but you can do something similar.

```
var a = {value: 5};

function myFunction(x){

    if(x.value != 4){
        x.value = 4;
    }
}

myFunction(a);
```

Or with array:

```
var a = [5];

function myFunction(x){

    if(x[0] != 4){
        x[0] = 4;
    }
}

myFunction(a);
```

Also I would recommend using typesafe comparing (===), (!==)

Comment: An object is a far better design choice for the description given by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `myFunction` a copy of the value of `x` is passed to the function. So if you call it passing `a`, the numeric literal 5 would be passed there. As you have stated you want to alter the value of `a`, when the argument value you pass to `myFunction` is different from 4. You can do fairly easily by referring to the `a` directly in the body of your `if` statement. The runtime would first check in the function `myFunction` if a variable with name `a` has been defined. Since there isn't any variable `a` defined inside `myFunction`, it will look at the scope where `myFunction` is defined, global scope. Since there `a` is defined it would assign the value of 4.

```js
var a = 5;

function myFunction(x){

    if(x != 4){
       a = 4;
    }   
}

myFunction(a);

console.log(a);
```

Comment: I think this is defeating the object of the OPs question, it looks more like a bad choice in the OPs design.

Comment: Its not the point. When i call it for b, i want b = 4, and when called for c, c = 4

Comment: Unfortunately what you want to do is not going to work. Or it will in very specific circumstances and will be fragile,

Comment: @AleksanderHauzer That you have to understand is that whatever you name the name of the variable you pass to the `myFunction`, this would be always a copy of the original value. passing there the copy of this value you can't alter the original value.