# Why Doesn't My Function Have Scope Of The Javascript Variables?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get my head around something re Scope/Closures.

I've setup an index.html with an app.js pulled in via `<script>`

The functions are accessible in things like `<button onclick="increment();>"...`

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <button onclick="increment();"></button>
     <h2 id="number"></h2>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
let total = 0;

function increment() {
    total += 1;
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = total;
}

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('total is: ', total);
}, 5000)
```

So Scenario A above has a function that when called in html, increments the `let total...` fine. Then it posts it in the h2 tag/html. This works fine.
And the timeout is there to test that 5 seconds later, it is indeed the `let total...` variable that's been incremented (i wondered before if i was creating a global variable within the function).

Scenario B calls a function (`startGame()` which *itself* calls the increment function with total passed in) but this *doesn't* work. Why would it lose scope of total?

**app.js**

```
    let total = 0;

function startGame() {
    console.log('game has started');
    increment(total);
    console.log('game has finished');
}
function increment(tot) {
    tot += 1;
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = tot;
}

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('total is: ', total);
}, 5000)
```

Comment: What's the error exactly?

Comment: `tot +=1` will only increment the local variable. It has no effect on `total`.

Comment: Acutally there is no pass by reference in javascript - See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass Variables by Reference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

> Scenario B calls a function `startGame()` which itself calls the increment function with total passed in, but this doesn't work.

That has nothing to do with it.

> Why would it lose scope of total?

Because you've changed your `increment` function. You are no longer incrementing the global `total` variable, you are incrementing your local `tot` variable that was declared as a parameter.