# How do I pass a reference in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need a function, that changes the value of a passed attribute. You find an non-functioning example below. How do I have to pass the attribute and access the parameter? Thank you in advance!

```
let top = {target: document.getElementById("header").style.top};

animate(top, 50);



function foo(attribute, value) {

        //some code

        attribute.target = value + "px";

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass Variables by Reference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript)

Comment: Among other issues, you shouldn't use `top` as a variable if you're writing for a browser.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Is there an alternative?

Comment: @MoritzFerdinandRocker almost any other variable name that is not `top` is an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not passing the element as argument directly?

```js
let header = document.getElementById("header");

foo(header, 'top', 50);

function foo(element, attribute, value) {
  //some code

  element.style[attribute] = value + "px";
}
```

I've made the code on the fly, but you get the idea, right?

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass refences to primitives like Strings, Numbers and Booleans. You can, though, pass references to objects, in your example the DOM element:

```
let [top, attr, subAttr] = [document.getElementById("header"), "style", "top"];

foo(top, 50, attr, subAttr);

function foo(element, value, attr, subAttr) {
    if (subAttr) {
        element[attr][subAttr] = value+"px";
    else {
        element[attr] = value+"px";
    }
}
```

Comment: You also can't redefine `top` at least not in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Thank you! But can I pass "style.top" separately?

Comment: You could pass it as an array ["style", "top"] or use the String "style.top" and do split(".") in the function that handles it.

Comment: Added an example how to pass those additional parameters.

Comment: @connexo open the console and type: `let top = 1` ==> `SyntaxError: Can't create duplicate variable that shadows a global property: 'top'` You can use `var top = 1` without error, but it won't actually do anything.

Comment: Well, you cannot do it at global scope. You can, though, do it locally scoped. Is anybody still doing anything globally scoped?