# how is array updated & returned in JS function

Tags: javascript

Am trying to add/remove elements from an array declared inside a function. I have been able to add or remove and access the updated array for the same.

For accessing the array I have used two different approaches.

1. Have created an inner function which returns the array.
2. Have returned the array from the main function and accessing the same using dot notation.

Here is my code:

```js
function test() {
  let myArr = [];

  const getMyArr = () => myArr;

  const add = n => {
    myArr.push(n);
    return () => {
      myArr = myArr.filter(a => a !== n);
    };
  };


  return {
    myArr,
    getMyArr,
    add
  };
}

let myTestRun = test();


let remove3 = myTestRun.add(3);
let remove7 = myTestRun.add(7);
let remove8 = myTestRun.add(8);
console.log("myArr after insertion", myTestRun.myArr);
console.log("getMyArr() after insertion", myTestRun.getMyArr());
remove7();

console.log("myArr after removing", myTestRun.myArr); //still returns the old array without any modifications
console.log("getMyArr() after removing", myTestRun.getMyArr()); //returns the modified array. how? Why didn't it work before?
```

What I do not understand is why did `myArr` did not have any modifications and how come `getMyArr()` function has returned the updated value. I used to believe that both the `myArr` point to the same object. So, any modifications on the `myArr` should be reflected via both the approaches. Why am I wrong. What is the reason behind this different return values?  Please explain.

Comment: Because `let myArr` and `return { myArr, ... }` no longer reference the same Array. The variable has been changed, the property on the returned object has not. and `getMyArr()` returns the value of the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Because [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a new array.

The object returned by `test` and the local variable both are referencing the same array. Mutating the array (`push`, `pop`, `splice` etc) through either of the references will modify the array.

This is only up until the call to `remove7()`. The `filter` method returns a new array and `myArr` variable is now referencing this new array while `myTestRun.myArr` still references the old array created initially. If you log `myTestRun.myArr === myTestRun.getMyArr()` at every point, it will start returning false after `remove7()`.

But, `getMyArr()` is still taking closure over the `let myArr` variable. So, it will always log whatever the variable is currently holding at that moment

Here are some similar questions which might make it clear:

- [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000)
- [Does Javascript pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494)
- [Pass Variables by Reference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611)
- [Javascript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640)

Comment: _The variable let myArr and the myArr property of the object returned by the test function aren't referencing the same array any more._

How is that? Have I not returned `let myArr` which must be the same property returned from `test`?

Comment: @Imran Yes, you have. Updating `myTestRun.myArr` will update the `myArr` variable because both of these are pointing to the same array in memory. But, only until `remove7()` is called. `filter` returns a **new** array and `myArr` variable now points to a new memory location. While the `myTestRun.myArr` is till pointing to the old array. Updating one array will not affect the other array

Comment: I get it. Can you please edit your post and add it in your answer so that I could accept it.

Comment: @Imran updated the answer and added links to some additional questions which are very similar

Answer (score 1):

You change the object reference of `myArr`, but you need the same object reference and for deleting, you could splice the unwanted elements.

```js
function test() {
  let myArr = [];

  const getMyArr = () => myArr;

  const add = n => {
    myArr.push(n);
    return () => {
      var i = myArr.length;
      while (i--) if (myArr[i] === n) myArr.splice(i, 1);
    };
  };

  return { myArr, getMyArr, add };
}

let myTestRun = test();

let remove3 = myTestRun.add(3);
let remove7 = myTestRun.add(7);
let remove8 = myTestRun.add(8);
console.log("myArr after insertion", myTestRun.myArr);
console.log("getMyArr() after insertion", myTestRun.getMyArr());
remove7();

console.log("myArr after removing", myTestRun.myArr); //still returns the old array without any modifications
console.log("getMyArr() after removing", myTestRun.getMyArr()); //returns the modified array. how? Why didn't it work before?
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its better if you use

```
function test() {
  this.myArr = [];

  this.getMyArr = () => this.myArr;

  this.add = n => {
    this.myArr.push(n);
    return () => {
      this.myArr = this.myArr.filter(a => a !== n);
    };
  };
}

let myTestRun = new test();


let remove3 = myTestRun.add(3);
let remove7 = myTestRun.add(7);
let remove8 = myTestRun.add(8);
console.log("myArr after insertion", myTestRun.myArr);
console.log("getMyArr() after insertion", myTestRun.getMyArr());
remove7();

console.log("myArr after removing", myTestRun.myArr); //still returns the old array without any modifications
console.log("getMyArr() after removing", myTestRun.getMyArr());
```