# How to filter an array without another array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

So far I tried this but it returns unfiltered array:

```js
function filterRangeInPlace(array, min, max) {
  array = array.filter(item => (item >= min && item <= max));
  console.log(array);
}

let arr = [5, 3, 8, 1];

filterRangeInPlace(arr, 1, 4);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: `.filter()` *always* creates a new array. Your code doesn't work because the assignment to `array` in the function is an assignment to the parameter and JavaScript is a pass-by-value language.

Comment: To actually achieve what the question title requests you'd have to write a function to "smush" the array in place to get rid of filtered-out entries.

Comment: [Pass Variables by Reference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26610095/3082296)

Comment: The function `.filter()` is doesn't like a `for` loop, This function actually apply the filter on array entities and return a new filtered array, It doesn't make changes on a actual array like `for` loop, So when you need to filter any array then you must need to take a variable which holds filtered array result or just use `for` loop and remove unsatisfied entries from the array which affects on original array elements

Comment: @NeelRathod To be fair, a for loop can totally create a new filtered array. Under the hood, I would guess that .filter() uses a loop of some kind.

Comment: This code works fine.
I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it's actually important to do the filtering in-place without creating another array, you have to go sort-of old school and iterate through the array with two indexes, copying values along the way. Every time you hit an element that fails the filter test, you increment one of the indexes but not the other one. At the end of that, you reset the array `.length` to the trailing index:

```
function filterInPlace(array, fn) {
  let from = 0, to = 0;
  while (from < array.length) {
    if (fn(array[from])) {
      array[to] = array[from];
      to++;
    }
    from++;
  }
  array.length = to;
}
```

This has the advantage of being O(n), with just one pass over the array, while the solutions involving `.splice()` are O(n<sup>2</sup>).

To do your "range check", you could write another function to create a filter predicate given a minimum and a maximum value:

```
function rangePredicate(min, max) {
  return n => n >= min && n <= max;
}
```

Then you can pass the return value of that to the filter function:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, ... ];
filterInPlace(arr, rangePredicate(0, 10));
```

Comment: Thank You for Your awesome answer, this is what I looking for - fast and cheap (for memory) way to filter an array.

Comment: Please, can You add Your version of `fn` for completeness of the answer? Thank You

Comment: @RobertHovhannisyan Well `fn` can be any function, just like a function you'd pass to `.filter()`.  If it returns `true` then the value is included in the final array, otherwise it isn't.

Comment: @RobertHovhannisyan answer extended.

Comment: Oh, that's great. Now everything is clear. Thank You again!

Answer (score 4):

You need to return the new filtered array and assign it to a variable (such as `arr` itself):

```js
function filterRangeInPlace(array, min, max){
  return array.filter(item => (item >= min && item <= max));
}

let arr = [5, 3, 8, 1];

arr = filterRangeInPlace(arr, 1, 4);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This works of course but it doesn't satisfy the "without another array" part of the question.

Comment: That was a pretty smart way to filter an array but I agree with @Pointy in this case. But Thank You anyway for Your good answer!

Answer (score 3):

Return the value and set it equal to itself.

```
function filterRangeInPlace(array, min, max) {
  return array.filter(item => (item >= min && item <= max));
}

let arr = [5, 3, 8, 1];

arr = filterRangeInPlace(arr, 1, 4);

console.log(arr);
```

Or you could of course omit the function entirely with:

```
let arr = [5, 3, 8, 1];

arr = arr.filter(item => (item >= min && item <= max));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: That interesting and short answer. Thank You for Your effort!

Comment: @RobertHovhannisyan Huh? Is that not exactly what you were trying in your question that didn't work?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `.filter()` for this, since it returns a new array rather than modifying the original array. You can loop over the array yourself, removing elements that don't match the condition.

You need to do the loop in descending order of index, because removing an element shifts the indexes of all the remaining elements down and you'll end up skipping the next element if you do it in increasing order. This also means you can't use a built-in function like `.forEach()`.

```js
function filterRangeInPlace(array, min, max) {
  for (let i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (array[i] < min || array[i] > max) {
      array.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}

let arr = [5, 3, 8, 1];
filterRangeInPlace(arr, 1, 4);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You do if you use `array.splice()`. I guess you could go forward and decrement `i`.

Comment: But you can't use `forEach`, it doesn't provide a way to back up.

Comment: I'd do what I wrote in my answer because somewhere in my head I'm still a C programmer on a pdp-11.

Comment: That was an awesome solution. Thank You very much for Your code!