# How to store a style property in a variable as the route?

Tags: javascript, constants

I'm not able to store the style of an element in a variable and use it as the route:

```
let store = element.style.height;

store = 100px;
```

I'm trying to reduce my code by creating a constant that limits the max value of an input like follows:

```
const limitMaxVal = (whatToLimit, whatToStyle) => {
    let maxVal = parseFloat(whatToLimit.max);
    let minVal = parseFloat(whatToLimit.min);

    if (whatToLimit.value >= maxVal) {
        whatToLimit.value = maxVal;
        whatToStyle = maxVal / 10 + "%";
    } else if (whatToLimit.value <= minVal) {
        whatToStyle = minVal / 10 + "%";
    } else {
        whatToStyle = whatToLimit.value / 10 + "%";
    }
}
```

The constant has two variable. *whatToLimit* is the input I'm limiting and *whatToStyle* is what the input is styling. In this case I'm styling the height of a canvas but I want to use the same constant for the width, background-color... Which brings me to my problem: I can't find a way to store the style of an element as a route. If I store it like it follows I'll get the value of the height:

```
inputHeight.oninput = function() {
    limitMaxVal(this, canvas.style.height);
};
```

Another example of using the same constant would be:

```
inputWidth.oninput = function() {
    limitMaxVal(this, canvas.style.width);
};
```

I also tried using [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) but it doesn't work either:

```
const limitMaxVal = (whatToLimit, whatToStyle) => {
    let maxVal = parseFloat(whatToLimit.max);
    let minVal = parseFloat(whatToLimit.min);

    if (whatToLimit.value >= maxVal) {
        whatToLimit.value = maxVal;
        eval(whatToStyle) = maxVal / 10 + "%";
    } else if (whatToLimit.value <= minVal) {
        eval(whatToStyle) = minVal / 10 + "%";
    } else {
        eval(whatToStyle) = whatToLimit.value / 10 + "%";
    }
    
    this.focus();
}


inputHeight.oninput = function() {
    let store = "canvas.style.height";
    limitMaxVal(this, store);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code, what got passed into the `limitMaxVal` function is a **value** of the style property, not the **reference**, while the function needs to know **where** to assign new values to, not **what** the current value is. Read the answers in [Pass variables by reference in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript) to understand more about it.

To explain using your own code:

```
// This creates a variable with name `store` and value '200px',
// assuming that `element.style.height` is '200px'
let store = element.style.height;

// This changes the value of `store` to '100px',
// nothing happened to `element.style.height`
store = 100px;

// At the end, `store` is '100px',
// `element.style.height` remains '200px'
```

Based on what you wrote there I suggest passing the style object and the property name to the function, something like this:

```
const limitMaxVal = (whatToLimit, styleObj,  propertyName) => {
    let maxVal = parseFloat(whatToLimit.max);
    let minVal = parseFloat(whatToLimit.min);

    if (whatToLimit.value >= maxVal) {
        whatToLimit.value = maxVal;
        styleObj[propertyName] = maxVal / 10 + "%";
    } else if (whatToLimit.value <= minVal) {
        styleObj[propertyName] = minVal / 10 + "%";
    } else {
        styleObj[propertyName] = whatToLimit.value / 10 + "%";
    }
}
```

And here is how to use it:

```
inputHeight.oninput = function() {
    limitMaxVal(this, canvas.style, 'height');
};
```

Comment: Yes! That was it! Thank you so much for your quick answer and for showing me styleObj[propertyName] and pass by reference. Made my day!!

Answer (score 0):

@Kelvin nailed it already - kudos!

However, I played around a bit and came up with this alternative approach. Here you specify the `whatToStyle` object and property as a string. However, it requires the target object to be in the global name space (`window`).

And please note: the min and max limitation is now done in a single expression using `Math.min()` and `Math.max()`.

```js
const canvas=document.getElementById("canvas"),
      inp=   document.getElementById("inp");

function limitMaxVal(whatToStyle){
  return function(ev){
    let inp=ev.target
    let wts=whatToStyle.split('.'), ob=window[wts.shift()];
    while (wts.length>1) ob=ob[wts.shift()];
    ob[wts[0]]=Math.min(Math.max(inp.value,inp.min),inp.max)+'%'
  }
}

// this is how you apply it on an input element:
inp.oninput=limitMaxVal("canvas.style.height");
```

```css
#main {height:150px; width:300px}
#canvas {height:15%; width:300px; background-color:blue}
```

```html
<input id="inp" type="number" value="15" max="100" min="10"><br>
<div id="main"> <div id="canvas"></div> </div>
```