# Calling a function by addEventListener, but the function only work one time, can not call it again

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function that making the password to be text if I click the eye, if you click again, the eye will close. I may use this function for other input, so I separate the function, so I do not use the way that `eye.onclick=function(){...};` Below is my code, but my code only work one time, first time I click it, the eye open, but click again, the eye can not close, is that I need to remove the EventLister?

```
var password = document.getElementById('passWord');
var eye = document.querySelector('#eye');
var flag = 0;
var eyeOpen = function(obj,eyes,flag){
            if (flag===0){
                eyes.className="eye_open";
                obj.type = 'text';
                flag=1;
            }else{
                eyes.className = "eye_close";
                obj.type = 'password';
                flag = 0; 
            }
        }

eye.addEventListener('click', function () { 
        eyeOpen(password,eye,flag);
    });
```

Comment: the scope of the `flag` that you edit isn't actually the flag you imagine, it's the flag that is only in the function.. it only works once because from 0 to 1.. then if u click again, it receives the same 0.. forever and ever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the discussion here: [Pass variables by reference in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript). The problem is that you're passing `0` around, when what you want to be doing is changing `flag` directly.

```
var password = document.getElementById('passWord')
var eye = document.getElementById('eye')
var flag = 0

var eyeOpen = function(obj, eyes) {
  if (flag === 0) {
    eyes.className= 'eye_open'
    obj.type = 'text'
    flag = 1
  } else {
    eyes.className = 'eye_close'
    obj.type = 'password'
    flag = 0
  }
}

eye.addEventListener('click', function () {
  eyeOpen(password, eye)
})
```

The downside of this is that if you're reusing this code in several places, you could have several flags to keep track of. Rather than doing that, you could check the classList (or the input type), which would mean one less variable to keep track of:

```
var password = document.getElementById('passWord')
var eye = document.getElementById('eye')

var eyeOpen = function (obj, eyes) {
  var isOpen = eyes.classList.contains('eye_open')
  // This would also work:
  // var isOpen = obj.type === 'text'

  if (isOpen) {
    eyes.className = 'eye_close'
    obj.type = 'password'
  } else {
    eyes.className= 'eye_open'
    obj.type = 'text'
  }
}

eye.addEventListener('click', function () {
  eyeOpen(password, eye)
})
```

Comment: But I want to use the eyeOpen  function for the other eye,  so I may have flag_2, so, the put the flag as a parameter in the function. Do I  have another way to use flag in eyeOpen()?

Comment: There is, I just added that in my edit. There's really no need for that variable at all, because you can check the `#eye`'s classList or the input's type.

Comment: Thanks! I use the similar as yor,  that is if eyes.className=="eye_close", than open,else close.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var password = document.getElementById('passWord');
var eye = document.querySelector('#eye');
var flags=[0] //index based stuff
//if you have another eye..
//flags.push(0)
function openEye(index,password){
  flags[index]++
  if(flags[index]%2){password.type="text"}
  else{password.type="password"}
}
eye.addEventListener('click',function(){
  openEye(0,password) //for each eye the values can change :|
})
```

```html
<input id="passWord" type="password"/>
<button id="eye">THE EYE</button>
```

Comment: How can I take the function outside,  I want to use the function in other eye

Comment: so my answer wasn't even a bit useful? yikes :{

Comment: That's good, just not what I expected, but your answer may help another person.