# How to add to a global variable with a functions return value (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, object, return-value

I have a callback function which takes two parameter and a global variable that I would like to add to with the value returned from this function. However the variable remains the same. Please help!

```js
let sum = 0;
const myArr = [{name: 'dj', value: '2'}, {name: 'kd', value: '3'}];

function addObjValue(arr, total) {
    arr.forEach(element => {
        const val = element.value;
        total += checkObjValue(val);
        console.log(total);
    })
}

function checkObjValue(x) {
    switch(x) {
        case '2':
            return 1;
            break;
        case '3':
            return 5;
            break;
    }
}

addObjValue(myArr, sum); // sum remains 0
```

Comment: In javascript variables are, more or less, passed by *value*. This means you cannot write *into* some passed variable such that that change would be reflected on the *outside*. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7744611

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a local variable and save totals there, then just return total value

```
function addObjValue(arr) {
    let total = 0
    arr.forEach(element => {
        const val = element.value;
        total += checkObjValue(val);
        console.log(total);
    })
    return total
}
```

And after that make your sum equal to returned value

```
sum = addObjValue(myArr);
```

**Update**
One more thing. To get sum from an array you can use `reduce` method

```
arr.reduce((totalSum, currenElement) => {
    return totalSum + currenElement.value
}, 0 /*first value of totalSum (by default equal to the first element of the array)*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue:

- `total` is scoped under `addObjValue` so it doesn't add to final `sum`
- break inside switch-case is unreachable as it comes after `return 1;`

You can make below 2 changes to make it work.

```
let sum = 0;
const myArr = [{name: 'dj', value: '2'}, {name: 'kd', value: '3'}];

function addObjValue(arr, total) {
    arr.forEach(element => {
        const val = element.value;
        total += checkObjValue(val);
    })
    return total; // change 1: returning total
}

function checkObjValue(x) {
    switch(x) {
        case '2':
            return 1;
        case '3':
            return 5;
    }
}

sum = addObjValue(myArr, sum); // change 2: assigned return value back to sum
```